# Design pattern for using foreachRDD in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I just read the documentation:[official link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd). At the end of this part, it recommend to use connection pool with `foreachPartition` to achieve best efficiency. I didn't find the class `ConnectionPool` in spark source code. Is it just a presudo example? Is there any practical example? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a Spark class. As said in documentation:

> One can maintain a static pool of connection objects than can be reused as RDDs of multiple batches are pushed to the external system, thus further reducing the overheads.

It should be **your** specific class, which will hold connections that you want to have in a pool - i.e. JDBC Connections. [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database-connection-pooling-with-scala) is an example implementation

Comment: so that connection pool should be a separate object outside the object which my `foreachPartition` in?

Comment: @G_cy It can be some third party project or your own implementation inside you project. It's just a class that holds a pool of Connection objects, You can write own class or use existing libraries - it depends what you need

Comment: actually, I was considering object Serialization problem. Do I need to create my pool in the foreachpartition cycle(this will create a pool in each workder node)?